# Looking for a method to handle a large diagram model for a generic purpouse context

Tags: dictionary, uml, entity-relationship

After years of developing i've decided to draw a mind "map"/"diagram" to organize all projects i've created.

I should be able to:

1. create visual relations between

   - projects
   - frameworks / libraries
   - programming languages
   - hosting services
2. add/remove items easily without reorganize everything at each
   change ( maybe some auto-ordering tool ) since i've tons of projects
   and temporary works
3. add popup rich-text notes for each item

**which kind of model do you suggest to use for this purpose?**

Is there any Linux/Crossplatform ( possibly freeware ) software that could accomplish tasks above?

i've tried to use some basic software for UML creation such as google draw / libreoffice draw .. but they are poor of features for large models.

Comment: try [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) and [MindMaple](http://www.mindmaple.com/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class diagram with stereotyped classes (e.g. `<<idea>>`) for that purpose. Depending on the tool it might look a bit clumsy but likely feasible. Enterprise Architect has a special MDG for mind mapping where special connectors (and stereotyped classes) are used.

FWIW: I'd use a simple mind map freeware. Those are designed specifically towards mind mapping (as their name suggest). E.g. Freemind saves data in XML format and it should be possible to move data over to XMI via XSLT.